# List newest file, by type (.txt), after searching recursively, in a terminal

Tags: linux, terminal, find, grep, ls

I'm trying to get my terminal to return the latest .txt file, with path intact.  I've been researching ls, grep, find, and tail, using the '|' functionality of passing results from one utility to the next.  The end result would be to have a working path + result that I could pass my text editor.

I've been getting close with tests like this:
find . | grep '.txt$' | tail -1

..but I haven't had luck with grep returning the newest file - is there a flag I'm missing?

Trying to use find & ls isn't exactly working either:

find . -name "*.txt" | ls -lrth

..the ls returns the current directories instead of the results of my find query.

Please help!

Answer (score 3):

You're so very close.

```
vi "$(find . -name '*.txt' -exec ls -t {} + | head -1)"
```

Answer (score 2):

```
find /usr/share -name '*.txt' -printf '%C+ %p\n' | sort -r | head -1 | sed 's/^[^ ]* //'
```

Comment: Sadly, yours will blow up if you have files and/or directories with newlines in their names. Unusual, I know, but a fully-robust solution should handle those. Other than that, not a bad solution.

Comment: @Chris: True…but why did you single me out?  That is true of every other solution since they are all using head or sort.  Sort can be dealt with, but head requires perl or perhaps awk.

Comment: Probably because yours is one of the first answers. Usually, I play by "fastest gun in the west" rules, which means that if you're not the first poster (or your post isn't within a minute or two of the first poster), usually it doesn't count. (Unless it's a really innovative answer, of course.)

Answer (score 2):

If you have bash4+

```
ls -t ./**/*.txt | head -1
```

edit the latest txt file

```
vim $(ls -t ./**/*.txt |head -1)
```

*ps: need enabled `shopt -s globstar`* in your .bashrc or .profile...

Answer (score 1):

You can use the stat function to print each file with just the latest modification time and name.

find . -name "*.txt" -exec stat -c "%m %N" {} \; | sort